# ContextMenuStrip size and scroll on different resolution monitors

Tags: c#, contextmenu, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors with different resolutions(one of 1280x1024 and the other is of 1536x2048)
I create a `ContextMenuStrip` of a button with the following properties:

1. the menu has about 20 items.
2. the item's image is 48x48.
3. Menu's `ImageScalingSize` is 48x48.

when the main form is on the 1st screen with the 1280x1024 resolution, the scroll of the menu appears and this is accepted. but when the form is located on the second screen the scroll appears although there's enough space to expand all the menu items.

How does the `ContextMenuStrip` get its initial size based on the resolution, and when does the scroll should appear?

**Notes**

- I tried creating it in both runtime and design time and i got the same results.
- I use .Net 3.5

Comment: I'll randomly guess you have a two monitor setup and you dragged the window from one to the other.  Even if you could fix the bug, which you can't, it isn't worth the trouble since your user will never run into it.  Instead spend time on making your CMS more usable so the user never has to scroll.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant ,actually i didnt find an answer to this till now, but i guess i have to decrease the number of items in the main menu and make them as subitems.